# SSL module in Python3.10.2 is not available, getting error in pip install on redhat 7

Tags: ssl, openssl, redhat, python-3.10

sudo make:
Following modules built successfully but were removed because they could not be imported:
_hashlib              _ssl

Could not build the ssl module!
Python requires a OpenSSL 1.1.1 or newer

pip install:
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url

(Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping